# Nested Components in React Router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to build a simple weather report app using React Router. This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory} from 'react-router-dom';
var Main = require('Main');
var Weather = require('Weather');
var About = require('About');

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={Main}>
            <Route path="/Weather" component={Weather} />
            <Route path="/About" component={About} />
        </Route>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

when I try the code above, I get a warning that says:

`You should not use <Route component> and <Route children> in the same route; <Route children> will be ignored`

And when I change my code to this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory} from 'react-router-dom';
var Main = require('Main');
var Weather = require('Weather');
var About = require('About');

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={Main} />
        <Route path="/Weather" component={Weather} />
        <Route path="/About" component={About} />
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

I get an error that says `A <Router> may have only one child element`.

What should I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap all the routes in a `div`, like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <div>
           <Route path="/" component={Main} />
           <Route path="/Weather" component={Weather} />
           <Route path="/About" component={About} />
        </div>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Or use [Switch](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Switch.md):

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Switch>
           <Route path="/" component={Main} />
           <Route path="/Weather" component={Weather} />
           <Route path="/About" component={About} />
        </Switch>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can fix the second problem to have only one child element
by putting for example div tag inside Router and put all your routes in it as the follows

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
      <div> 
        <Route path="/" component={Main} />
        <Route path="/Weather" component={Weather} />
        <Route path="/About" component={About} />
      </div>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```